# Using ArrayLists and Objects

Tags: object, arraylist

This is my object class

```
class Baller
{
    public String name;
    public double height;
    public double weight;
    public String country;

    public Baller()
    {
        name = "";
        height = 0;
        weight = 0;
        country = "";
    }

    public Baller(String name1, double height1, double weight1, String country1)
    {

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }
}
```

I need to create a arraylist that adds the name, height, weight and country of each player.

This is how i initialized it:

```
ArrayList<Baller> playersNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is where i add the player information:

```
System.out.println("What player would you like to add (Enter Name, Height, Weight and Country)");

String name = TextIO.getlnString();
double height = TextIO.getlnDouble();
double weight = TextIO.getlnDouble();
String country = TextIO.getlnString();
players = new Baller(name, height, weight, country);
playersNames.add(players);
```

This is how i try to print the arraylist

```
System.out.println("The roster is:"+playersNames);
```

When I print it out its says: Baller@13bad12

Answer (score 0):

To output the name, use :

```
System.out.println("The roster is:" + players.getName());
```

What you need to know with object is that when you try to print them directly, the toString() method will be called.

In the case of your Baller object, it is not defined so the reference is printed. You can override it to output the name if you want :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.getName();
}
```

Then 
`System.out.println("The roster is:" + players);` would work.

**Edit** : To print all the player values, simply concatenate them to the return String :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Name : " + this.getName() + ", Height : " + this.getHeight() + ", Weight : " + this.getWeight() + ", Country : " + this.getCountry();
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it

Comment: and when i do that it just prints out null. I put it at the end of my baller class

Comment: Make sure name was defined. I see that your constructor with parameters do nothing. If null is returned then it means that the name is null.

Comment: Why does it only print out the name what about the other three variables

Comment: Then simply concatenate the other values to the return string.. I'll edit the post.